# Adding a non WCF SOAP wsdl as external content type in sharepoint manager

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, external-content-type, external-list

This is location to my wsdl, it is WSDL created by Spring WS:

http://foo.bar/local/rpc/file.wsdl

I am trying to add the connection to external data source from **sharepoint designer**.

In the selection there are only 3 options:

1. .NET type
2. SQL Server
3. WCF Service

I tried using WCF Service, by putting the wsdl to Service Metadata URL and Service Endpoint URL, getting error `Cannot find any matching endpoint configuration`.

How can I add my SOAP WSDL as external content types. I want to use it in my **external list**.

Answer (score 1):

This post seems a bit old but it might help someone else.

1) Open SharePoint Designer then open your site

2) On the left click External Content Types

3) then select External Content Type on the ribbon

4) Fill in the name for the ECT

5) then click on External System link "Click here to discover external data sources and define operations"

6) click on Add Connection and in the data source type select WCF Service and click OK

7) In the connection properties properties enter something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add more details, like for example how you get to that dialog?

Comment: I have added the steps above

Comment: This is a webservice created in .NET, its ASMX. Question was how to consume web services created with java, spring ws, jaxb etc.